# Описание привилегии Защищённые вопросы

Tags: дефект, локализация

[Читаю](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions)

> Участники, имеющие соответствующие привилегии, могут защитить, или наоборот, отменить защиту любого вопроса, опубликованного **не позднее**, чем один день назад, при условии, что на вопрос уже имеется ответ от участника с репутацией менее 10 баллов.

Может должно быть **не ранее** чем один день назад?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Этот кусок, как мне кажется, переведён довольно неудачно и недословно. Также текущий перевод не содержит последнего полезного предложения в скобках. Кусок "уже имеется ответ" не соответствует действительности, так как данный ответ может быть удалён (по-хорошему, так именно и должно быть, иначе зачем отмечать вопрос, как защищённый?). Здесь зря упустили прошедшее время, что было бы более корректно.

На мой взгляд, можно вполне перевести почти дословно и всё будет понятно:

> Любой вопрос, которому, по крайней мере, один день, может быть отмечен защищённым или у него может быть убрана эта отметка, при условии, что вопрос уже получал хотя бы один ответ от участника с репутацией менее 10 баллов (подобным участникам будет запрещено публиковать дальнейшие ответы после того как вопрос отмечен как защищённый).

Comment: А  не лучше "Любой вопрос, старше одного дня......."?